# Crash reporting in app delegate error: Attempt to insert nil value (key: BreakpadMinidumpLocation)

Tags: ios, parse-platform, invalidargumentexception

I'm using Parse and following [this](https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart#analytics/crashreporting/ios/swift/existing) short snippet of documentation. The line `ParseCrashReporting.enabled()` in my AppDelegate.swift file is what is throwing the compile time error:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: **attempt to insert nil value (key: BreakpadMinidumpLocation)'**

What is `BreakpadMinidumpLocation`? Is this a bug within Parse or perhaps something in my Info.plist? I followed all steps correctly in the documentation.

Comment: Did you contact the developers of the Parse SDK yet?

Comment: Yes apparently it was an internal bug that Parse fixed in their SDK release 1.7.4 as noted here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1448023458843905